# Trying to create a distro file on Python using setuptools. Following Head First Python chapter 4 "code reuse" **Solved, stupid noob mistake**

Tags: python

**Noob losing his mind!!**
My code seems identical to the code provided except for the names. I have retabbed using the CTRL + ] so I'm pretty sure my indentation isn't the problem.

```
'''
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name= 'letter_manip',
    version= '0.1',
    description= 'The Head First Python Search Tools',
    author= 'jim',
    author_email= 'jim@gmail.com'
    #url= 'headfirstlabs.com'
    my_modules= ['letter_manip'],
)
'''
```

The error code is as follows:

```
'''
  File "setup.py", line 11
    my_modules= ['letter_manip'],
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
'''
```

I have also tried copy and pasting into python using the terminal and I get the following:

```
'''
  File "setup.py", line 11
    my_modules= ['letter_manip'],
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
'''
```

I have been banging my head against a brick wall with this for a few days and I haven't been able to find a solution online. I'd appreciate any help :) (ps I'm using linux mint if that makes a diff, python 3.8.10)

Comment: You forgot to add ',' after author_email='jim@gmail.com'

Comment: OMG I'm such an idiot!!! Thanks so much, and that explains why I was getting the same error with URL!! It should have been a clue. Thanks bud.